# Worker role starts with reasonable memory usage but then memory usage increases constantly

Tags: memory-management, pinvoke, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role which runs multiple threads(I used [ThreadedWorkerRole](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2012/02/combining-multiple-azure-worker-roles.html)). My worker role downloads some data and then images related to that data. Everything works fine locally but when I deploy the app on azure, It starts by showing a reasonable memory usage(48 MB) but then it shoots to the 800 MB within 1 or 2 hours. My application did care disposing the objects with lots of "using" statements and closing the streams properly. But I still wonder what cause the memory to jump at such a high value. One More thing, I have used RETSLib(PInvoke library to hit RETS server) which downloads data and images. Can it be the issue of Unmanaged code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can definitely be the issue of unmanaged code leaking memory. Is RETSLib a .net wrapper on librets? Some references to php implementations of librets [leaking memory](http://mail.crt.realtors.org/pipermail/librets-users/2011-October/003701.html).

You mention "downloads some data and then images related to that data". Are you using Entity Framework to get this initial data or store it into SQL? If so I am assuming that you dispose of the ObjectContext. There have been instances where EF 4.0 seems to have some memory issues.
A [link (old)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666304/memory-leakage-issue-in-entity-framework) that talks about this.

Could have added this as a comment but stackoverflow would not allow me to do so on account of my low rep points

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. yes I am using librets(.net wrapper) and I am not using EF at all. One more thing, I am definitely not able to unload the unmanaged library while worker role is in running. How could I handle this leakage?

Comment: Unloading a dll will not solve the memory leak since the load operation loads a dll into the application's process space. You could try putting just the dll load and unload into a separate process and killing that process (?)